# Phone Gap [error] cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT

Tags: java, android, cordova, ant

I am trying to get phone gap to work on android and my command outputs the following:

```
phonegap build android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
[error] cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
```

When searching this error message I get a lot of hits, but everyone else seems to have much more verbose error messages, when this is all I get. Even with the -d or -v option that is what I get.

I am using Windows 7 x64

My PATH variable looks like this:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Roaming\npm;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANT_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;
```

> %JAVA_HOME% , %ANDROID_HOME% and %ANT_HOME%

all lead to the correct places when I type them into my search bar.

Just typing "java" and "ant" into my command line gives me results.

Any ideas where I should start looking? Are there error logs somewhere?

Comment: have you installed the cordova client as well? `npm install -g cordova` The phonegap client uses the cordova client for local builds.

Comment: @Dawson Loudon yeah I have.

Comment: In which folder have you installed ant? (it seems cordova builds fail if ant is installed in a folder containing round brackets). Try to run `%userprofile%\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\check_reqs.bat` to see if displays more details about the problem.

Comment: Please see my answer below @Desmond

Comment: It also doesn't like spaces in your account name, mind you

Answer (score 7):

If you are sure of yours paths try to type `android` in `cmd` if it says: `'xcopy' was not recognized`.

then add to your path:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32; %SystemRoot%; %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
```

Comment: Perfect! Works like charm

Comment: if anyone having executing command ant, please make sure ..... error.  this is the solution too !!!!

Comment: Worked for me too. @GianFS, you have to add it to the end of your PATH variable in your environment variables(http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure how this resolved the issue but try this out it will resolve for sure.

This is due to ANT tools could not find **tools.jar** in JRE lib directory. When I copied tools.jar from **JDK lib directory to JRE lib directory**.
Restart the system and the problem was absolutely solved and the build was successful when I ran the command "cordova -d platform add android". Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

He is using Windows 7, brew is for OSX.

To install ANT for windows try this:
https://code.google.com/p/winant/

Answer (score 2):

You need to install ant before build.

How to install ant? Use this one.

try this one. Make sure you install node.js first

1.Download and install Homebrew by executing following command in cmd:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

2.Install Apache Ant via Homebrew by executing

```
brew install ant
```

3.Build project

```
phonegap build android
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using cordova and the following worked for me:

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```

After this refresh eclipse acted a bit wonky just remove and add the project back again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete this folder :

```
%USERPROFILE%\.gradle
```

Answer (score -1):

Please add C:\Windows\System32 in your PATH variable. It worked for me!

Comment: So which file was it that was found in that directory?