# Unable to resolve Phone Gap [error] cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT 3

Tags: android, cordova, ant, sencha-touch-2

unable to run sencha/phonegap application in android..
getting exception "cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT 3" here are the version i installed..

```
D:\testapp>sencha -version   
Sencha Cmd v4.0.1.45
[ERR] No such property : version
 at com.sencha.cli.AbstractCommand$Properties.getProperty(AbstractCommand.ja
va:417)
 at com.sencha.cli.AbstractCommand.parseConfigParam(AbstractCommand.java:441
)
 at com.sencha.cli.AbstractCommand.processConfigParam(AbstractCommand.java:4
91)
 at com.sencha.cli.AbstractCommand.configure(AbstractCommand.java:114)
 at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:136)


D:\testapp>phonegap -version  
3.4.0-0.19.7

D:\testapp>cordova -version  
3.4.0-0.1.3

D:\testapp>ant -version  
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013

D:\testapp>phonegap run android  
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...  
[phonegap] using the local environment  
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...  
[error] cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT  

D:\testapp>phonegap build android  
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...  
[phonegap] using the local environment  
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...   
[error] cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT  

Thanks in advance
```

Comment: Please see my (@Desmond) answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312332/phone-gap-error-cmd-command-failed-with-exit-code-enoent/22952259#22952259

Answer (score 0):

Check the following steps:

1. `cordova create testapp com.example.testapp TestApp`
2. `cd testapp`
3. `cordova platform add android`
4. `cordova build android`

After this you should copy your project and paste it into the immediate `www` folder of your cordova project. And then run

1. `cordova run android`

From your above snippet it seems you have `cordova` installed in your system.
NB: The above CLI steps are for cordova versions 3.x

Comment: D:\Cordova_ex>cordova create hello com.example.testapp TestApp
Creating a new cordova project with name "TestApp" and id "com.example.testapp"
at location "D:\Cordova_ex\hello"

D:\Cordova_ex>cd hello

D:\Cordova_ex\hello>cordova platform add android
Creating android project...
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT

Comment: I have edited my answer. There was a mistake. Try again.

Comment: Still the same,D:\Cordova_ex>cordova create testapp com.example.testapp TestApp
Creating a new cordova project with name "TestApp" and id "com.example.testapp"
at location "D:\Cordova_ex\testapp"

D:\Cordova_ex>cd testapp

D:\Cordova_ex\testapp>cordova platform add android
Creating android project...
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\sharana.bv\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\cordova\src\superspawn.js:112:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:795:12)

Comment: I guess you check you java PATH variable.

Comment: here are my path variablesC:\Program Files\SenchaCmd\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.1.45;
C:\Ruby193\bin;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;
C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin;
E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130717\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130717\sdk\tools;
E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130717\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130717\sdk\platform-tools;
C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;
C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin;
C:\sencha-touch-2.3.1-gpl\touch-2.3.1;
%ANT_HOME%\bin;
C:\Users\....\AppData\Roaming\npm;
C:\Users\....\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\bin;
C:\Windows\System32\wbem;
C:\Program Files\nodejs\

Comment: @AnandGupta Maybe a noob question, but... What do you mean copy your project to the imediate www folder of cordova project?

Comment: Immediate means, inside the root folder of android project, there is www folder. I indicated that one.