# VS2013 Community, Windows 8.1 , Cordova build/debug error

Tags: java, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2013

Windows 8.1 64 Bit

VS2013 Community with Cordova apps addon (auto configured by VS)

I have an Error when I try to debug/run the hello world sample (brand new project, just created, no changes)

```
Error   2   C:\Users\Louis\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\create.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
```

Based on similar issues other people are getting, I see that my Java was not working properly. Check-requirements tool in the cordova folder complained about java. I eventually got my java working (fixed and reinstalled, made sure the right paths and envrionmental variable were set, and cordova is now a happy camper.

I however still get this issue in VS2013 when I try to debug/build the default app.

I am running a 64 bit OS, but installed the 32 bit JDK. (From previous experience lead me to do this when I was troubleshooting). But as stated, cordova seems happy with the requirements check.

VS is set to use auto system variables, and is not complaining about any of them.

I added the directory variables to my "path" system variable for both user and system.

Added JAVA_HOME var that points to the root java dir. (User and system)

Added JAVA var which points to root java dir\bin. (User and system)

I would greatly appreciate any input.

Comment: Have you tried to run the plain _ant_ as instructed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24443550/1744702)?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion, I did however get it working, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally able to build/run.

Seems because I created the project earlier when the Java-environment was broken, the project kept being broken. Created a new project now that the Java environment is fixed, and it builds!. I cant however use the same name as the previous project, otherwise the build fails. There is probably some record stuck somewhere about the previous app (name) 's config.

For now I just changed the name and am moving on.