# Cordova always return ant error

Tags: android, cordova, ant

I already spent a day to setup `cordova 3.5 android enviroment` on `windows 7`. 
I have no idea why this is so HARD !!!

When I command "cordova platform add android". I always get this error.

`executing command 'ant' make sure you have ant installed and added to your path`

[image]

Below is my setup

```
under variable for username
ANDROID_HOME C:\Development\adt-bundle\sdk
ANT_HOME     C:\Development\apache-ant-1.9.4
JAVA_HOME    C:\Development\Java\jdk1.8.0_05

PATH         %ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANT_HOME%\bin;C:\Users\vzhen\AppData\Roaming\npm

Testing command
java -version FINE
ant -version FINE
npm -version FINE
cordova -version FINE
```

Let me know what i am missing?

Comment: Take a look at the second answer (the one that talks about adding extra paths for system root): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312332/phone-gap-error-cmd-command-failed-with-exit-code-enoent

Comment: @DawsonLoudon work like charm. thank you so much. cannot believe this error not related to ant but xcopy.

Comment: Glad it worked! Going to add an answer/passthrough for others that find this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312332/phone-gap-error-cmd-command-failed-with-exit-code-enoent)

It appears to actually be an issue related to `xcopy` and can possibly be solved by updating the `PATH` with this:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32; %SystemRoot%; %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
```