# android Cordova 6.0 CordovaActivity not loading external website

Tags: android, cordova

I have installed Cordova 6.0 in my system and created a sample android project. I am trying to load external URL within the default webview of the activity, but its giving an network error. Wifi is also enabled in my testing device.Internet permissisons are also set in the manifest file. Can someone provide the correct solution?
Thanks in Advance.

My code:

public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

```
    try
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
         super.loadUrl("http://www.google.co.in/");

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.v(TAG, e.toString());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need whitelist plugin in the last cordova version, to enable external resources. Check this plugin

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Comment: But when I am trying to add any plugins to my existing project. Its giving the following error."Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-whitelist':Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT". When I googled it I found the following links.     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23422961/cordova-cannot-add-android-failed-with-exit-code-enoent                  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312332/phone-gap-error-cmd-command-failed-with-exit-code-enoent     But my issue is not fixed.  Thanks

Comment: How are you trying to install it? use `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist` in the folder of your project

Comment: Yes. This issue  first occurred when I was adding android platform to my project using CLI.

Comment: Are you using windows? try opening your console with admin privileges.

Comment: Yes. I am using windows 7 OS and tried in the console with Admin Privileges only...

Comment: Well, I dont know how to help you in this, sorry